# Prototype inheritance with Knockout observables

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototypal-class-design, knockout.js

I'm trying to write a JavaScript library to allow inheritance with knockout.

The fundamental problem when implementing inheritance in Knockout is that each Knockout observable is its own instance, thus if you try this:

```
 x = function () {};
 x.prototype.m = ko.observable();
 y = function () {};
 y.prototype = new x();
 z = new y();
 //z.m == y.prototype.m == x.prototype.m
```

The behavior I'm trying to get goes like this:

```
//psudo-code, I know this wouldn't work
x = function () {};
x.prototype.a = ko.observable();
y = function () {};
y.prototype = new x();
y.prototype.b = ko.computed(function () { return this.a() });
//enabling this:
z = new y();
z.a(5);
a = new y();
a.a(12);
// z.b() == 5, a.b() == 12
```

Here's my proposed solution:

```
var getParams = function (args, index) {
    return args.length > index + 1 ? Array.prototype.slice.apply(index) : Array.prototype.concat.call([], args[index])
};

var Ladder = function () {};

Ladder.prototype.init = function (config) {
    var self = this;
    if (!(config instanceof dontInit)) {
        // Only initialize if config is passed, this allows us to create sub-prototypes
        if (this.attachEntity) this.entity = config;
        for (var prop in self) {
            var extender = self[prop];
            if (extender instanceof doAttach) {
                self[prop] = extender.extender.apply(self, extender.args); // || ('' + extender.extender); // if the function doesn't return a value perhaps it only performs operations? Leave a tatle tale behind?
            }
        }
        if (this.populateObject) {
            for (var prop in config) {
                if (config.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                    var val = config[prop];
                    if (ko && ko.isObservable(self[prop])) self[prop](ko.unwrap(val));
                    else self[prop] = val;
                }
            }
        }
        for (var prop in self) {
            var extender = self[prop];
            if (extender instanceof doExtend) {
                self[prop] = extender.extender.apply(self, extender.args); // || ('' + extender.extender); // if the function doesn't return a value perhaps it only performs operations? Leave a tatle tale behind?
            }
        }
    }
}

Ladder.prototype.attachEntity = true;
Ladder.prototype.populateObject = true;

Ladder.prototype.attach = function (propertyName, extender) {
    var args = getParams(arguments, 2);
    this.prototype[propertyName] = new doAttach(extender, args);
}

Ladder.prototype.extend = function (propertyName, extender) {
    var args = getParams(arguments, 2);
    this.prototype[propertyName] = new doExtend(extender, args);
}

Ladder.inherit = Ladder.prototype.inherit = function () {
    var ctor = function (config) {
        this.init(config);
    };
    ctor.attach = Ladder.prototype.attach;
    ctor.extend = Ladder.prototype.extend;
    ctor.inherit = Ladder.prototype.inherit;
    ctor.prototype = new this(new dontInit());
    return ctor;
};

Ladder.prototype.attachComputed // doComputed

Ladder.createPrototypes = function (prototypes) {
    return duplicatePrototypes(prototypes);
}

var dontInit = function () {};

// doAttach is called before config and should attach a computed or observable, though you may attach any value you like.
var doAttach = function (extender, args) {
    this.extender = extender;
    this.args = args;
};
var doComputed = function (computed) {
    return new doExtend(function () {
        return ko.computed(computed, this);
    }, []);
};
// doExtend is called after config and would normally perform some init work
// naming convention for extenders is _00Name where 00 is a priority (00 will run before 01) and Name is a descriptive name
var doExtend = function (extender, args) {
    this.extender = extender;
    this.args = args;
};
```

**My questions are:**

1. **Are there performance issues with this type of inheritance**? i.e. if I use this paradigm to build complex objects with long inheritance chains, will there be a performance hit vs some other 'better' inheritance paradigm?
2. **Does this make for clear code?** Is it obvious what is going on when I define an object like this:

   ```
   var myObject = usefullBaseClass.inherit();
   myObject.attach("newProperty", ko.observable, 5);

   var instanceOfMyObject = new myObject();

   // instanceOfMyObjecct is an instance of myObject and has an observable
   // property called newProperty which is unique to this instance
   ```

Comment: I am most curious, what would you be modeling that requires a long inheritance chain ? I have yet to find something that requires more than 3 levels.

Comment: My current use case consists of a set of base classes used to generate a grid, I then create inherited classes for each instance of the grid, the user is then able to extend the classes for grid A without affecting the behavior of those classes in grid B (the goal is for a very customizable grid).
The current paradigm would only involve 2-3 deep chains, but  that will likely change as I continue adding features. For example the Row class will likely be extended by a sub-class AggRow, when a sub-class AggRow is created for an individual grid it will have an inheritance chain 3 deep.

Comment: I'd also like to plan for deeper inheritance if I can.

Comment: Good enough, can you update the snippet under 'Does this make for clear code', the snippet should include how you created the usefullBaseClass.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question,

- *Are there any performance hits ?* I don't see problems, it would not be slower then building the objects in an old skool manner
- *Does this make for clear code?* Your sample code would not run, you need to provide a sample that would actually run.

Furthermore:

- You should run you code through JsHint

  - You are missing semicolons
  - You are declaring some variables more than once in the same function
- Your code has `Ladder.prototype.attachComputed // doComputed` <- Pointless
- Your code has `return duplicatePrototypes(prototypes);` <- `duplicatePrototypes` is not provided
- `dontInit` <- `doNotInit` reads better, also there must be a better way to avoid initialization ;)
- `doAttach` is a constructor, so definitely wrongly named. `AttachedValue` mayhaps?
- Anonymous functions are a pain in stacktraces, if you are going to create a custom OO approach, then I would avoid avoid anonymous functions like the plague.
- `// naming convention for extenders is _00Name where 00 is a priority` <- I do not believe this works, `for (var prop in self) {` does not pre-sort property names, at least that is not guaranteed
- The distinction between `doAttach` and `doComputed` is unclear, are the comments possibly out of date? `// doAttach is called before config and should attach a computed or observable` <- It seems from the code that I would attach a computable through `doComputed` ?
- This:

  ```
  //Note: extender.extender might simply return undefined
  self[prop] = extender.extender.apply(self, extender.args);
  ```

  is better than

  ```
  self[prop] = extender.extender.apply(self, extender.args); // || ('' + extender.extender); // if the function doesn't return a value perhaps it only performs operations? Leave a tatle tale behind?
  ```
- I guess `var self = this;` comes from your knockout background. If you are not using closures, then there is no good reason to use this.
- Do not drop newlines from `if` statements;

  ```
  if (ko && ko.isObservable(self[prop])) 
      self[prop](ko.unwrap(val));
  else 
      self[prop] = val;
  ```
- `if (ko)` should be at the very start of your script, there is no point if knockout is not available

All in all, I think I would not use your library until it has matured a bit more.